# Wrong length for Gensim Word2Vec's vocabulary

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to train the `Gensim Word2Vec` model by:

```
X = train['text']    

model_word2vec = models.Word2Vec(X.values, size=150)
model_word2vec.train(X.values, total_examples=len(X.values), epochs=10)
```

after the training, I get a small vocabulary (`model_word2vec.wv.vocab`) of length `74` containing only the alphabet's letters.

How could I get the right vocabulary?

**Update**

I tried this before:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(lower=True)
tokenized_text = tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)

model_word2vec.train(sequence, total_examples=len(X.values), epochs=10
```

but I got the same wrong vocabulary size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply the model with the kind of corpus it needs: a sequence of texts, where each text is a *list-of-string-tokens*. If you supply it with non-tokenized strings instead, it will think each single character is a token, giving the results you're seeing.

Comment: I have tried, I but I get the same .wrong vocabulary size

Comment: Then you must still be passing strings or something else other than an iterable sequence of lists-of-strings. The only docs I find online for a `texts_to_sequences()` method suggest it converts texts to lists-of-integers, which would be wrong. Try printing `sequence[0]`, or if that doesn't work, `iter(sequence).next()` to see an example of the individual texts you're passing to `Word2Vec`. If it's not a list-of-strings like perhaps `['hello', 'world']` then you're not giving `Word2Vec` the right input.

Comment: I have found an issue in `tokenization` process. I changed the tokenization method, and now it's work.